# adding two button which shows different messages when pressed ( only in html )

Tags: html, button, onclick

Can someone please help me create a 4 different button which shows the different messages when pressed individually.

However with the below coding I am using now,  when I press the button2 it shows the same message as button1 even thou the Button2 have its own message.

Please note I can only use the HTML codes as I am using this code on html only enabled page. Please help.

Comment: Could you please post code snippet here, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be achieved if you aren't able to use JavaScript on your page.  What's the restriction?

Comment: <style>
#alertt {
  display:none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

</style>
<body>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('alertt').style.display='block'">Buton1</button>
<div id="alertt">

  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  message1
</div>

Comment: #Martin I am using a page on website builder, the page only allows to use html code < I tried running script but it does not work >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Are you expecting something like this ?**

```css
.alert {
 display: none;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #f44336;
 color: white;
}

.closebtn {
 margin-left: 15px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: right;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert1').style.display='block'">Buton1</button>
<div id="alert1" class="alert">
   <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> message1
</div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert2').style.display='block'">Buton2</button>
<div id="alert2" class="alert">
   <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> message2
</div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert3').style.display='block'">Buton3</button>
<div id="alert3" class="alert">
   <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> message3
</div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert4').style.display='block'">Buton4</button>
<div id="alert4" class="alert">
   <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> message4
</div>
```

> Create div element with unqiue id and add event listener on them, and add common class to style them

**Update**

> you can also write javascript like below in html file

```
<html>
 <script>
  console.log('Javascript works here');
 </script>
</html>
```

**Update 2**
I have created a much cleaner way of your requirement (but using script tag)

```css
.alert {
 display: none;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #f44336;
 color: white;
}

.closebtn {
 margin-left: 15px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: right;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<button data-msg-id="alert1">Buton1</button>
  <button data-msg-id="alert2">Buton2</button>
  <button data-msg-id="alert3">Buton3</button>
  <button data-msg-id="alert4">Buton4</button>
  
  <div id="alert1" class="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> message1
  </div>
  <div id="alert2" class="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> message2
  </div>
  <div id="alert3" class="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> message3
  </div>
  <div id="alert4" class="alert">
   <span class="closebtn">&times;</span> message4
  </div>
  
  <script>
    console.clear();
    const buttonsList = document.querySelectorAll('button'), closeBtnList = document.querySelectorAll('.closebtn');
    buttonsList.forEach(each => each.addEventListener('click', handleBtnClick));
    closeBtnList.forEach(each => each.addEventListener('click', handleCloseBtnClick));
    
    function handleBtnClick(evt) {
      document.querySelectorAll('.alert').forEach(each => each.style.display = 'none');
      document.querySelector('#'+evt.target.dataset.msgId).style.display = 'block';
    }
    
    function handleCloseBtnClick(evt) {
      evt.target.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You can also write javascript in html file within script tag (Answer updated), what website builder are you using ?

Comment: @ Sameer Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for but the button are not aligned in same line (previously I had 4 buttons they were aligned in same line but now the button 1 is in first line and rest 3 buttons are are in second line) . Also is there any way for us to close the current message automatically if we click on any other button and open the message of the new button we clicked. ( like if we click outside of the box the message box closes)  Thanks a lot for your help I was looking for this solution from weeks

Comment: @Learningcurb what website builder are you using ?, are you able to write javascript in html file within script tag ?

Comment: I am using squarespace

Comment: No the script tag doesn't work only the html tag works

Comment: @Learningcurb there are some answers [here](https://forum.squarespace.com/topic/9648-where-do-i-upload-javascript-files/) which can help you to add script in squarespace and answer updated have a look

Comment: @ Sameer I understand that but I can not use the javascript inside my particular coding or can not run script tag. Do you how we can align the buttons in one line as with the coding you provided the button are not aligned in same line (previously I had 4 buttons they were aligned in same line but now the button 1 is in first line and rest 3 buttons are are in second line) . Also is there any way for us to close the current message automatically if we click on any other button and open the message of the new button we clicked. ( like if we click outside of the box the message box closes). Help

Comment: I used your updated code with the script tag but unfortunately it does't work on my html page. Need something with the html code please

Comment: I need something similar functionality but inside the button form <style>
.collapse > a{
  background: #cdf;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.collapse:focus{
  outline: none;
}
.collapse > div{
  display: none;
}
.collapse:focus div{
  display: block; 
}
</style>
<div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
  <a>Collapse 1</a>
  <div>Content 1....</div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
  <a>Collapse 2</a>
  <div>Content 2....</div>
</div>